# Changing datagrid cell backcolor with respect to the previous cell value in WPF datagrid

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I have created a datagrid in WPF which has cell values continuously changing, But I am not able to change the backcolor of a the cells with respect to the previous value of cell, 
for Example if the value of the cell changes from 10 to 20 the the color of the cell should become green indicating that the value increased and if the value becomes 5, the cell backcolor should become red indicating that the value has decreased. I have done that in winforms on cellvaluechange event of datagridview,  but in WPF I am not able to do the same. any of the professionals have done anything regarding that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property `IsIncreased` in your cell's `DataContext` to hold a `Nullable<bool>` according to increasing/decreasing.

```
public class DatagridCellViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool _isIncreased
    public bool? IsIncreased
    {
      get{ return _isIncreased; }
      set{ 
          _isIncreased = value, 
          FirePropertyChanged("IsIncreased");
         }
    }

    //this is going to store the value you have in your table. Don't forget to bind it to the cells content
    private int _dataValue;
    public int DataValue
    {
      get{ return _dataValue; }
      set{
            if(_dataValue != value)
            {
               IsIncreased = _dataValue < value
               _dataValue= value;

               FirePropertyChanged("DataValue");
            }             
         }
    }

    //other properties and methods
}

public class DataGridViewModel
{

     private ICollection<DataGridRowViewModel> _myDgRows = new ObservableCollection<DataGridRowViewModel>();
     public ObservableCollection<DataGridRowViewModel> MyDgRows { get{ return _myDgRows;}
}

public class DataGridRowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged // don't forget to implement this interface
{
     //put here fields and properties you want to display in a row in your datagrid
     //that means as many fields as many columns you have

    private DataGridCellViewModel _cellValue;
    public int CellValue
    {
      get{ return _cellValue; }
      set{
            if(!_cellValue.Equals(value))
            {
               _cellValue= value;

               FirePropertyChanged("CellValue");
            }             
         }
    }
}
```

Create a `DataTrigger` to set the background of the cell according to the `IsIncreased` value:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDgRows}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ChangingValues" Width="SizeToCells">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Name="ContentTbx" Text="{Binding CellValue.DataValue}" />
               <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CellValue.IsIncreased}" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                  </DataTrigger>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CellValue.IsIncreased}" Value="False">
                     <Setter TargetName="ContentTbx" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
               </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Set the IsIncreased prop every time when the cells Data prop changed

**EDIT :** Don't bind table but an ObservableCollecition calls MyDgRows. For this a DataGridViewModel instance should be your DataGrids DataContext.

Probably you need to deal with int-string conversion in the DataValue prop.

For that matter I googled

> datagrid wpf

the first link was [this](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)

and

> datatriggers datatemplate

the second result was [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)

and they covers almost the whole issue. **Be more self-sufficient**

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just need to know that would that work if i am binding the datagrid by a datatable. Also please help when and how should i fire the event? when updating the datarow? Sorry but Please elaborate "FirePropertyChanged" field stub.

Comment: Please tell me why am i getting the PropertyChanged always null? when should i change this property in my code. Sorry to ask these little things but i am doing for the very first time. Please help me out in that ways .

Comment: DatagridCellViewModel obj =  new DatagridCellViewModel();

DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)mygrid.Items[0];
            dr[3] = newvalue;
            obj.DataValue = newvalue;
            mygrid.Items.Refresh();

IsIncreased always changes when i am updating the datavalue accordingly, true or false. But still i am getting the proprtychanged  null, am i missing out something? Please help me out..!

Comment: This is because the DatagridCellViewModel instance is not properly binded to the DataGridCells in your view. The very big advantage of the bindings is that you don't have to maintain your datachanges manually (you did it in your comment), because it is done automatically by the framework. Try to dig deeper in databinding and the usage of the MVVM model.

Comment: sure, I will get into the databinding concepts as well as MVVM model, But for now can you please help me in doing this kind of stuff. how and where can i bind the datagridcells to the DatagridCellViewModel instance? I have just created a datagrid in my Application.
 <DataGrid Name="mygrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,0,95">
then i pasted your code.

Comment: I created a table in the load event and the given that table as its datacontext. and i am keep updating the table as well as the values in the DatagridCellViewModel class. 
Please give me any link of the dummy project if you have or mail me.

Comment: Please tell me how can i properly bind the DatagridCellViewModel instance to datagridcels in my view. I have tried in many ways. Please help me out?

Comment: Many many thanks Buddy....! finally you helped me to get out of this problem. I am really grateful.

Comment: you can except the answer if you want to